# archive.org URL not handled properly in comment

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks

On [What should a job-seeker know about job non-descriptions?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52548/what-should-a-job-seeker-know-about-job-non-descriptions?noredirect=1#comment134815_52548) I wanted, given a point of seniority that was relevant to the description, to offer a crude metric of the date of earliest recorded webpage in archive.org.

The URL I gave was:

```
https://web.archive.org/web/19970415000000*/http://www.imsa.edu/~jhayward/
```

It seemed to be broken into two links and not obviously show someone else on the forum what I intended, which was to see the archive.org calendar page with 2 or so captures for the month. (I caught it quickly and used a URL shortener to circumvent the bug; the comment is the one edited to http://CJSH.name/first ).

I'll try commenting the admittedly odd URL in a comment to this post to see what the engine makes of it.

Comment: Here we go: https://web.archive.org/web/19970415000000*/http://www.imsa.edu/~jhayward/

Comment: [Test](https://web.archive.org/web/19970415000000*/http://www.imsa.edu/~jhayward/)

Comment: Well, problem is the "*" character which is used in the mini-markdown supported in comments. Can't see any solution with the bare URL, but if you wrap it as a link `[like this](https://web.archive.org/web/19970415000000*/http://www.imsa.edu/~jhayward/)` it works, see my above comment.

Comment: The dupe was wrongly closed as dupe of something else, hopefully reopened soon.

Comment: This is a test http://web.archive.org/http://iwataasks.nintendo.com/interview-club-nintendo.html#/game-and-watch-ball-reward/0/0